# How to activate iAd Network in iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I want to activate iAd Network in iTunes Connect but with no success, iAd network is still in "Contracts In Process".

I've entered contact informations, Bank Info is alreday entered for paid apps and Tax Info I don't have since I'm from Croatia.

Here is ss of "Contracts":
[image]

And when I go to setup "Bank Info" I see next:
[image]
.. so this means that I don't need to do anything here.

And when I go to "Tax Info" I see next:
[image]
.. so that also means that I don't have do anything here because I'm from Croatia and that step applys to Canada and US.

What do I need to activate the iAd Network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fill out the US tax forms -- take a look at your screenshot: Note that U.S. tax forms are required for everyone.

Comment: I still got the status 'pending bank'? And bank info is still the same...

Comment: After 1 hour solved and bank info.

Comment: I waited a while and the bank info solved itself as well.  Apple should improve this so that we know when banking info will be mysteriously transferred from existing info, or so we can trigger this ourselves.

Comment: Thank you for the "US tax forms are required for everyone". That should be in bold.